# Second sign-in causes infinite redirect loop after the first successful login MVC .NET 5 OWIN ADAL OpenIDConnect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, openid-connect

first post so be gentle! :)

I'm developing an MVC .NET 5 web app for Office 365 and am using the OpenIDConnect framework. I have set up OWIN (3) and ADAL(2) and my Azure AD Application. There is no user actioned login, the home controller has an [Authorize] attribute attached, forcing the immediate login redirect to Azure AD. I am not using roles in any of my Authorize attributes.

**The Problem**: I can log in to my applications successfully - ONCE! After the first login, I close the browser (or open a new browser on a different machine) and I hit the app again. It redirects me to the Azure AD login screen which I sign into and then it continuously redirects between the app and Azure until I get the infamous 400 headers to long issue. Looking into the cookie store, I find that it's full of nonces. I check the cache (Vittorio's EFADALCache recipe, although I was using the TokenCache.DefaultShared when this problem was discovered) and it has hundreds of rows of cache data (Only one row generated with a successful sign in).

I can see as the redirects occur via the output window that a new access and refresh token is being generated each round trip:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Verbose: 1 : 31/07/2015 12:31:52: 15ad306e-e26d-4827-98dc-dea75853788a - AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeHandler: Resource value in the token response was used for storing tokens in the cache
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 31/07/2015 12:31:52: 15ad306e-e26d-4827-98dc-dea75853788a - AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeHandler: Resource value in the token response was used for storing tokens in the cache
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 31/07/2015 12:31:52:  - TokenCache: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 31/07/2015 12:31:52:  - TokenCache: Deserialized 1 items to token cache.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Verbose: 1 : 31/07/2015 12:31:52: 15ad306e-e26d-4827-98dc-dea75853788a - TokenCache: Storing token in the cache...
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 31/07/2015 12:31:52: 15ad306e-e26d-4827-98dc-dea75853788a - TokenCache: Storing token in the cache...
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Verbose: 1 : 31/07/2015 12:31:52: 15ad306e-e26d-4827-98dc-dea75853788a - TokenCache: An item was stored in the cache
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 31/07/2015 12:31:52: 15ad306e-e26d-4827-98dc-dea75853788a - TokenCache: An item was stored in the cache
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 31/07/2015 12:31:52: 15ad306e-e26d-4827-98dc-dea75853788a - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
    Access Token Hash: PN5HoBHPlhhHIf1lxZhEWb4B4Hli69UKgcle0w7ssvo=
    Refresh Token Hash: 3xmypXCO6MIMS9qUV+37uPD4kPip9WDH6Ex29GdWL88=
    Expiration Time: 31/07/2015 13:31:51 +00:00
    User Hash: GAWUtY8c4EKcJnsHrO6NOzwcQDMW64z5BNOvVIl1vAI=
```

The AuthorizationCodeReceived notification in my OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions is being hit when the problem is happening, so I know that Azure thinks the login was successful (or else the redirect back to the app wouldn't occur):

```
    private static void PrepO365Auth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        //Configure OpenIDConnect, register callbacks for OpenIDConnect Notifications
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {

                ClientId = ConfigHelper.ClientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/Account/SignedOut",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/",
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigHelper.ClientId, ConfigHelper.AppKey);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new EFADALTokenCache(signedInUserID)); // TokenCache.DefaultShared Probably need a persistent token cache to handle app restarts etc
                        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            context.Code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, ConfigHelper.GraphResourceId);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error/ShowError?signIn=true&errorMessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I have replaced (after discovering the problem) the Authorized attribute with my own Auth attribute, inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute, just so I could try and step into the Authorize code and see what's happening. I built a PDB file from the version 5 version of MVC 5's source code, but all that happens is that it jumps back into my own code :( That being said, I've overridden what I could and have found that **filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** is false, which makes sense, as that would cause the redirect back to Azure sign in.

So, I know that:

- Azure is accepting my login and returning the relevant tokens
- On the second login, before OnAuthorization, the filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is returning false
- my Azure Application configuration is fine, or it wouldn't authenticate at all

I think that:

- There is something in the MVC Identity setup that is wrong. Azure is working correctly or it wouldn't authenticate at all.
- It's not a cookie issue as the problem arises if you carry out the second login on a different machine

I'm sorry this is a bit long winded, but there are so many of these infinite redirect issues out there, I needed to explain why my situation was different!

What I'm looking for (if not an answer!) is a push in the right direction as to how I can debug further.

Appreciate any help you can give!

Andy

Comment: Have found the answer for anyone interested. It's a known bug in Katana where the Katana cookie manager and the ASP .NET cookie manager clash and overwrite each other's cookies. Full details and workaround here:
http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=System.Web%20response%20cookie%20integration%20issues&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: It looks like this issue isn't going to get fixed in ASP.NET 4, as it's still an issue today.  @AndyBullivent please put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @AndyBullivent - Did you ever solve this? We're seeing an intermittent redirect loop, I would love to know how this was resolved.

Answer (score 23):

Have found the answer for anyone interested. It's a known bug in Katana where the Katana cookie manager and the ASP .NET cookie manager clash and overwrite each other's cookies. Full details and workaround here:

http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=System.Web%20response%20cookie%20integration%20issues&referringTitle=Documentation

The SystemWebCookieManager shown below can now be found in the [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/) Nuget package.

Adding the code for when CodePlex dies:

```
//stick this in public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // ...
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            });

//And create this class elsewhere:
public class SystemWebCookieManager : ICookieManager
    {
        public string GetRequestCookie(IOwinContext context, string key)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            var webContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
            var cookie = webContext.Request.Cookies[key];
            return cookie == null ? null : cookie.Value;
        }

        public void AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }
            if (options == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
            }

            var webContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);

            bool domainHasValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Domain);
            bool pathHasValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Path);
            bool expiresHasValue = options.Expires.HasValue;

            var cookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);
            if (domainHasValue)
            {
                cookie.Domain = options.Domain;
            }
            if (pathHasValue)
            {
                cookie.Path = options.Path;
            }
            if (expiresHasValue)
            {
                cookie.Expires = options.Expires.Value;
            }
            if (options.Secure)
            {
                cookie.Secure = true;
            }
            if (options.HttpOnly)
            {
                cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            }

            webContext.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
        }

        public void DeleteCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, CookieOptions options)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }
            if (options == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
            }

            AppendResponseCookie(
                context,
                key,
                string.Empty,
                new CookieOptions
                {
                    Path = options.Path,
                    Domain = options.Domain,
                    Expires = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                });
        }
    }
```

I made a gist of it, too: https://gist.github.com/irwinwilliams/823f43ef8a5e8019a95874049dbb8b00

Comment: Thx!! Totally solved my problem! I have MVC project with owin auth middleware, first cookie auth then oidc. As soon as I placed Authorize attribute on anything I would get infinite loop and I could see the cookie auth entering ResponseSignedIn. Seems like System.Web was replacing the cookie. I do register out of proc session and read that Session could very well be an offender... anyways thx again!

Comment: Two toes up life saver ... Thanks

Comment: Thx I'm struct with these for past week.Now it's working fine :)

Answer (score 10):

I encountered this issue and applied ALL THE FIXES ON THE INTERNET.  None of them worked, then I went in and looked at my cookie.  It was huge.  Owin middleware was truncating it and then then [Authorize] attribute wasn't able to verify the identity -> send user to oidc -> identity good -- redirect to client -> truncate cookie -> can't verify in [Authorize] -> send user to oidc -> etc.

The fix was in [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 3.1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/) and using the SystemWebChunkingCookieManager.

It'll split the cookies and parse them together.

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
      AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
      CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
  });
```

Comment: Not sure what issue @Cyberpks had to resolve, but this is a perfect fix for the primary issue. Thanks a million to Scott Belchak!!!

Comment: to where do I send flowers

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have exactly the problem described, but I did have a redirect loop during OpenId connect based signin as well on my DEV machine.

In my case it was a simple error with cookies. I was accessing the protected URL over HTTP. Make sure you are accessing the protected URL on your relying party via HTTPS.

Once you are authenticated the authentication cookie will only be sent over HTTPS, this means that when you access a protected URL over HTTP, browser will not send your auth cookie with the request and hence the server will see you as unauthenticated. At this point server will redirect you to auth server (where you are already signed in). Auth server will redirect you back to original url, thus ensuring a redirect loop.

This should never be the case in your deployments because you should always use all-SSL in your app, if you have features like authentication. This reduces the risk of session hijacking.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. Could'nt change the url from HTTP to HTTPS due to other dependencies.Finally resolved by adding session_start and session_end in global.asax.cs

```
  protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // event is raised each time a new session is created     
        }

  protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // event is raised when a session is abandoned or expires

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code resolved my issue by adding session events in Golbal.asax.cs file.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // event is raised each time a new session is created     
    }



protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // event is raised when a session is abandoned or expires

    }
```

And by adding below code in public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) method of Startup.Auth.cs file

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
        });
```