# Azure AD B2C: Bad Request - Request Too Long HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long. After login

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azureportal

I know a similar question is already asked earlier [at stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100272/azure-portal-bad-request-request-too-long) but it didn't worked for me. Kindly read the entire question before answering/commenting.

I have implemented AD B2C in two web application all were working fine till last week. Now all of a sudden we are getting

> Bad Request - Request Too Long HTTP Error 400. The size of the request
>   headers is too long.

when the user tries to login into the website. Since my website requires every user to be logged in, it has blocked us completely.

My web app are also not working in incognito/inprivate window. Browser: Chrome, Firefox and Edge

When I open the application in chrome(not incognito) after deleting all the history I can see there are around 160+ cookies from the the web app url.

Yes too much cookies seems to be killing my webapp, but its happening even after deleting all the history of browser and in private browsing too.

Even I have reduced the claims attribute to 3 suspecting that more claims attributes might be increasing the header size. 
[image]

I have tried [this too](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2020943/http-400-bad-request-request-header-too-long-response-to-http-request) but in vain.

Bottom Line: Deleting cookies and reducing claims both are not working for us and we are blocked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check same by running against your localhost? Are you seeing the same issue?

Comment: @Ramakrishna: It works perfectly fine in localhost. it is happening in Azure only.

Comment: Some kind of infinite redirect loop maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this fixed after raising a ticket with Microsoft Support team.

***Cause:*** There is a well-known issue with Owin Middle ware where it doesn’t set the authentication cookie and we end up being in a login loop. I was using an older version of OWIN.

***Resolution:*** OWIN Version 3.1.0.0 has integrated the fix in terms of a cookie manager.

*NOTE:* In-spite of using the fix, we can run into issues if we have custom SESSIONSTATE handler being used in the application. In STARTUP.AUTH.CS, we will need to make the following changes

Old:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{});
```

New:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions   {
      AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
      CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager() 
  });
```

Below is the question discussing the same:

[Second sign-in causes infinite redirect loop after the first successful login MVC .NET 5 OWIN ADAL OpenIDConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747008/second-sign-in-causes-infinite-redirect-loop-after-the-first-successful-login-mv)

Hope this helps other. 
Happy Coding.

Comment: I'm encountering this issue for a site built from the .NET Core 3.0 default template.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when integrating Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure Active Directory) via OpenID Connect into my own implementation of an Identity Server with ASP.NET Core Identity, deployed on IIS.

After logging into Microsoft, some users have too much information in the cookies, so my troubleshooting focused on allowing my Windows Server to support the volume of additional data received in the header.

To achive this I have added two new values in the following Windows Registry path:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters**

| Name | Value Type | Value Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **MaxFieldLength** | DWORD | 65534 (Decimal) |
| **MaxRequestBytes** | DWORD | 415028 (Decimal) |

Here is the official Microsoft documentation that helped me resolve it: [HTTP 400 Bad Request (Request Header too long) responses to HTTP requests - Workaround 2: Set MaxFieldLength and MaxRequestBytes registry entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-bad-request-response-kerberos?source=recommendations#workaround-2-set-maxfieldlength-and-maxrequestbytes-registry-entries).